# Java-JTextField Validation

Tags: java, swing

I'm working on a Add new user form and I have to enable the Save button after validating following.

1.User name field must include some letters(either correct or wrong user name).

2.Password field and verify password field must include some letters(either correct or wrong password).

Comment: So what have you tried so far to achieve this.

Comment: Cross posted: http://www.coderanch.com/t/662266/GUI/java/Adding-validations-form Quit cross posting. Its annoying to spend time answering a question only to find out it has already been answered.

Comment: Ok, thanks for remind. I didn't notice my coderanch post after you answered it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might work for you. The example is not self contained. You need to create the form, the main etc... I'm just focusing on how to handle the check to enable the Save button when the JTextField focus get lost.

1) We add a lost focus event to the text field as follows:

```
private JTextField getTxtUser() {
    if (txtUser == null) {
        txtUser = new JTextField();
        txtUser.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent e) {
                getBtnSave().setEnabled(
                    !getTxtUser().getText().isEmpty() &&
                    !getTxtPass().getText().isEmpty());
            }
        });
    }
    return txtUser;
}

private JTextField getTxtPass() {
    if (txtPass == null) {
        txtPass = new JTextField();
        txtPass.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void focusLost(java.awt.event.FocusEvent e) {
                getBtnSave().setEnabled(
                    !getTxtUser().getText().isEmpty() &&
                    !getTxtPass().getText().isEmpty());
            }
        });
    }
    return txtPass;
}

private JButton getBtnSave() {
    if (btnSave == null) {
        btnSave = new JButton("Save");
        btnSave.setEnabled(false);
    }
}
```

A better approach might be to add an event listener to the surrounding document inside the JTextField as follows:

```
                txtUser.getDocument().addDocumentListener(new DocumentListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                getBtnSave().setEnabled(
                    !getTxtUser().getText().isEmpty() &&
                    !getTxtPass().getText().isEmpty());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                getBtnSave().setEnabled(
                    !getTxtUser().getText().isEmpty() &&
                    !getTxtPass().getText().isEmpty());
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent e) {
                getBtnSave().setEnabled(
                    !getTxtUser().getText().isEmpty() &&
                    !getTxtPass().getText().isEmpty());
                    }
                });
```

But requires mode code...

Comment: @Sandun Suranga Wijenayaka -  And what if you have more than two fields? Did you even look at the other solution which provide a more generic solution. Did you even respond to the other posting stating you found an answer. This is exactly why you should not be cross posting. The answer given here was the same as the answer given in the other posting. This person should not have had to spend time giving the same answer. You should have deleted the question.

Comment: You don't need the `FocusListeners`, you can do this with `InputVerifier`s, see [Validating Input](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification) for more details